# Module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'

Tags: python, django, sockets, server

I'm trying to run an OLD (2018) Django project on localhost.

However, when I use: `python manage.py runserver 192.168.23.12:8000`

I get from `Python37\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py`:

```
line 600, in connect
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'
```

I'm using a Window machine and I tried also to change `AF_UNIX` to `AF_INET` getting:

```
AF_INET address must be tuple, not str
```

Comment: You'll need to show more context for the traceback there. _Something_ is attempting to use an UNIX socket to connect somewhere. What is it? Which library or module is trying to do that?

Comment: You're right I update the post

Comment: That looks like there's a possibly unconfigured MySQL address. Is the `DATABASES`/`DATABASE_URLS` of the app using MySQL?

Comment: Thank you. EDIT: yes in the `settings.py` I can see DATABASES using `django.db.backends.mysql` and as HOST `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: Yep, you'd have to adapt that to your Windows environment. It's likely just `localhost` will do for HOST if you have MySQL running as per usual.

Comment: Thanks. But how should I change the `connections.py` file in order to avoid this error?

Comment: If I create a new Django project and I try to run it localhost, everything works

Comment: You don't want to change a file in `site-packages`. You'll need to change your Django project's configuration.

Comment: Ok nice thank you. And what file should I look at for fixing this?

Comment: The `settings.py` file. As I said, you will need to change the `HOST` from `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` to `localhost`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the elaboration in the comments:

The error stems from the Django MySQL machinery attempting to use an UNIX domain socket for connecting to MySQL, since it has been told to do so via the `settings.py` file's database `HOST`.

However, there are no AF_UNIX sockets on Windows, so that's bound to fail.

The fix is to use a TCP socket to connect to MySQL; that is, change the MySQL `HOST` to e.g. `localhost` instead of a socket path `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`.